# Target encoding for survival analysis

Tags: survival, cox-model, target-encoders

I was wondering if it is appropriate to use target encoding (Catboost) for a survival analysis problem (most likely I will approach it first with Cox Proportional Hazards). I have several variables with high cardinality, some of them have similar frequency of appearance. I am unsure whether target encoding is a good fit for censored subjects.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually curious exactly what the internal target encoding of catboost does in this scenario.

If I had to do the target encoding by hand e.g., for the accelerated-failure-time-loss-function [xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/aft_survival_analysis.html), I'd be tempted to use a regularized maximum likelihood estimate of the expected log-event time for the category you are trying to encode. In what follows, I'll ignore exactly how one would split the data to create the target encoding (e.g. split the training data into 5 folds and for each of the folds target-encode based on the other 4 folds), which is obviously very important, but as far as I can see is just the same as for non-survival data.

The simplest version of this is of course, if you assume an exponential model and just use
$$\log \left( \frac{c_e + \sum_{r \in \text{ category}} \text{event indicator}_r}{c_t + \sum_{r=1 \in \text{ category}} \text{time to event or censoring}_r} \right) $$
within each category. The $c_e$ in the numerator and $c_t$ in the denominator are constants $>0$ that ensure the logarithm can be calculated. One obvious way to pick them is as $c_e = \text{scaling factor} \times \sum_{r \in \text{ all records}} \text{event indicator}_r$ and $c_t = \text{scaling factor} \times  \sum_{r=1 \in \text{ all records}} \text{time to event or censoring}_r$.
Depending on how you set the $\text{scaling factor}$, you shrink the target encoding for smaller categories more or less towards the overall estimate. You probably want $c_e$ to be at least something like $0.5$ to $1.0$ (but, hey, it's a hyperparameter you can tune).

Answer (score 1):

First, before you jump into a model with high-cardinality predictors, see if you can use your knowledge of the subject matter or unsupervised learning methods to get around that problem. It might make sense to do things like combine related categories, etc. Harrell discusses those approaches in Chapter 4 of his [text](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) and [course notes](http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf), with examples of application in later chapters.

Second, if you intend to use boosted trees for modeling, consider whether there's anything substantially to be gained by replacing the levels of those categorical predictors (as-is, or with categories combined as suggested in the first paragraph) with their average target values. In that modeling context, are the risks of overfitting and bias introduced by target encoding worth it, if you can (with adequately slow learning) use all the predictors without overfitting?

Third, it isn't immediately obvious how you could reliably use target encoding when the target is a potentially censored survival time. One possibility that comes to mind is to use a cumulative hazard estimate and some measure of censoring fraction as "targets" for this purpose. The author of the R [`mice` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mice) recommends using individual Nelson-Aalen cumulative hazard estimates, provided by the package's `nelsonaalen()` function, as predictors along with censoring indicators for purposes of multiple imputation. See Section 9.1.8 of van Buuren's [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-toomany.html). But I'm not at all sure how well that use of individual estimates and censoring would carry over to the averaging used in target encoding, and I'm not aware of any use of that approach for target encoding in survival models. Finally, it's not at all clear how reliably you could use a model based on that type of target encoding for predictions on new data samples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the recommended docs! I will try the first approach and group as much as possible categories.